# jQuery mouseover/mouseout flickers

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="individual">
    <div class="change">change</div>
    <div class="picture"><img src....></div>
</div>
```

The `.change` has `position: absolute;` and is invisible. On mouseover `.picture`, I want `.change` to appear, and on mouseout, to disappear. If the individual clicks `.change` then something should happen.

Right now, when mouse goes over change, then it is treated as mouseout of picture, and so change starts to flicker!

I then made this jQuery:

```
$('.change').mouseout(function(){
    $('.picture').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).parent().children('.change').hide();
    });
});

$('.picture').mouseover(function(){
    var i = $(this).parent().children('.change').show();
});
```

This works fine only the first time! If I move out the picture, then when I come back on, and go on change, everything starts to flicker!! What do I do?!

Thanks

Comment: On mouseover, when the 'change' is displayed , does it show over the picture?

Answer (score 17):

Use 'mouseenter' instead of 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave' instead of 'mouseout'

```
$('.picture').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).parent().children('.change').hide();
});



$('.picture').mouseleave(function(){
    var i = $(this).parent().children('.change').show();
});
```

Comment: "they travel up the DOM with each mouseover / mouseout event triggering to see if the user has truly "entered" or "left" the given element."

Comment: Was looking for a React solution... The DOM hasn't changed. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

I have always found mouseout and mouseover to be rather buggy. Not sure why, you might try:

```
$(function() { 
    $('.picture').hover(function() {
        $('.change').show();
    },function() { $('.change').hide(); });
});
```

As long as the appearance of ".change" doesn't move ".picture", causing the hover to be broken, then this should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.change { 
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that hiding `.change` will move the `.picture` element to the place where `.change` used to be. This will trigger both `.mouseover()` and `.mouseenter()` so there's no point to replace.

You should change CSS positioning to absolute for both elements so removing `.change` won't move `.picture`