# Hovering over nested React component triggers parent component onMouseOut and infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React menu item that should surface a subcomponent on hover. When that subcomponent `info-icon` is hovered, a tooltip should pop open. which looks like this:

[image]

Here is the component:

```
const TestFunc = (props) => {
const { icon, label, data } = props;
const [hovering, setState] = useState(false);

return (
    <div className="menu-item" onMouseOver={() => setState(true)} onMouseOut={() => setState(false)}>
        <div className="menu-item-element">
            <div className="sub-menu-item-element">{icon}</div>
            <div className="sub-menu-item-element">{label}</div>
        </div>
        {hovering ?
            <Tooltip
                id="base"
                align="top"
                content={data.tooltipContent}
                variant="learnMore"
                className="menu-item-element"
                position="overflowBoundaryElement"
            />
            : null
        }
    </div>
);
```

But when I hover over the info icon, this triggers the `mouseOut` function then the icon disappears, which then triggers the `mouseOver` function and it just loops like that with the info icon flashing over and over.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image flickering issue in React when image is conditionally rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218108/image-flickering-issue-in-react-when-image-is-conditionally-rendered)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave

Answer (score 2):

In the icon use `onMouseLeave` instead to prevent bubble to parent. Or `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Wow that worked, not on the icon, I just changed it on the parent div like I had it. If you could explain a bit why that works I can accept your answer.